# ASP.Net Web API Authentication using OAuth

Tags: asp.net, api, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

We have planned to implement authentication in our API using OAUTH. For this purpose I read so many articles on web to explore it. After read these articles what I am understanding is

1. Send credentials to authorization server and after successful
   authentication it will send you the access token.
2. Use this access token for further calling of your api methods.

To authenticate our api user needs to pass the following parameters.

1. Authorization Token
2. Employee ID

What I am thinking is to pass these values via request headers. Problem is that these request headers can easily be viewed in browser console and someone can misused it easily. Please suggest Is this the right way to authenticate api or we used something else for this purpose?

Comment: Any suggestion guyz?